# Javascript object keys and values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

createSlice is
a function that accepts an object of reducer functions where  **keys** in the reducer object will be used to generate string action type constants like this:

```
const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state) => state + 1,
  },
})
```

That is ok but I am confused about this.
where are the **keys** and **values** of this object?

```
reducers: {
    increment(state) {
        state.value++
    },
    decrement(state) {
        state.value--
    },
    incrementByAmount(state, action) {
        state.value += action.payload
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are asking what in the `reducers` object is considered the "key" and what is the "value" within that object.

Given the reducers:

```
reducers: {
  increment(state) {
    state.value++
  },
  decrement(state) {
    state.value--
  },
  incrementByAmount(state, action) {
    state.value += action.payload
  }
}
```

The reducer keys, i.e. `increment`, `decrement`, and `incrementByAmount` are used to generate string action type constants and action creators. The "values" are the action creator functions that return action objects, i.e. `(arg) => ({ type, payload: arg })`.

Basic Example:

```
const increment = (payload) => ({
  type: 'increment' // <-- reducer key is action type
  payload
});

const decrement = (payload) => ({
  type: 'decrement' // <-- reducer key is action type
  payload
});

const incrementByAmount = (payload) => ({
  type: 'incrementByAmount' // <-- reducer key is action type
  payload
});
```

`createSlice` is a function that takes the configuration object you pass to it and it generates the reducer function and action creator functions. The values produced from the `reducers` property ***are*** the action creators.

Perhaps it would be easier to see when not using the object property assignment shorthand, and use functions explicitly instead.

```
reducers: {
  increment: function increment(state) {
    state.value++
  },
  decrement: function decrement(state) {
    state.value--
  },
  incrementByAmount: function incrementByAmount(state, action) {
    state.value += action.payload
  }
}
```

or

```
reducers: {
  increment: (state) => {
    state.value++
  },
  decrement: (state) => {
    state.value--
  },
  incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
    state.value += action.payload
  }
}
```

It should be clearer now the distinction between "key" and "value".

Comment: My question is just about the javascript language not redux,an object should have a key:value pairs but in the 2nd code what is `increment` a method or a key?

Comment: @Alvah_Franey I see. `increment` is a function, and in the `reducers` object the function identifier "increment" is the key, the function is the value. See [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) - "In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can be passed to other functions, returned from functions, and assigned to variables and ***properties***." - emphasis is mine. I've updated my answer with what is hopefully a clearer example.

Answer (score 0):

The keys are `increment`, `decrement`, and `incrementByAmount`,  the values are the functions themselves. These are "reducers", which are functions that act on your state.

It's roughly equivalent to saying this, but with a different syntax

```js
reducers: {
  increment: function(state) {
    state.value++
  },
  decrement: function(state) {
    state.value--
  },
  incrementByAmount: function(state, action) {
    state.value += action.payload
  }
}
```